# Strange "Undefined offset: 0"

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am using Laravel and just trying to assign one element to an array. But I can't do this, cause I am getting "Undefined offset: 0" error. But here is the thing. I can dump the desired element and clearly see a value. But I can't assign it to an array. What a heck?

Here is my code:

```
$string = $response->getItems()[0]->snippet->thumbnails->medium->url;
$blogger['img'] = $string;
```

Dumping $string gives a string.

```
"https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AJLlDp0ZDDmzdlnX9fxhDJgVuoY0T779ITk2-dKxNA=s240-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no"
```

But assigning this $string to an array gives this:

```
"Undefined offset: 0"
```

Comment: The "undefined offset" should refer to `$response->getItems()[0]`. If that doesn't exist, then I have no idea how you get any useful value into `$string`.

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of code, output, or error messages. These things should all go directly in the question as machine-readable text.

Comment: Got it, sorry...

Answer (score 2):

There no value in  `$response->getItems()[0]`

Do a var_dump on $response->getItems and you will see it is an empty array. Presumably it is an array.

Comment: If "there's no value in", how can a `$string` have value?

Comment: Reread my question and you will notice, that it contains a value.

Comment: Make sure the error is pointing to the line you think it refers to. Try `$blogger[] = "";` to make sure that you don't assign a key, when you should not. It is clear it is looking for a value in an array value assigned to `[0]`. Should be something in this order.